# laravel 5.6 : I get a error " Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL "

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm in the process of developing the backend of an application and I use laravel 
in recover I want to select securite question of this user

```
 $User_data = User::where('email', '=', $email)->leftJoin('secutitequestion', function($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'secutitequestion.user_id')->pluck('secutitequestion.securite_question1'
            ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question1'
            ,'secutitequestion.securite_question2'
            ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question2'
            ,'secutitequestion.securite_question3'
            ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question3');
        });
```

and I this what I get :

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on `users`.`id`
>   = `secutitequestion`.`user_id`' at line 1 (SQL: select `secutitequestion`.`securite_question1`,
>   `secutitequestion`.`answer_securite_question1` on `users`.`id` =
>   `secutitequestion`.`user_id`)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `->pluck` inside your `leftJoin` but you should call it outside. Please try my code below

```
$User_data = User::where('email', '=', $email)
                ->leftJoin('secutitequestion', function($join) {
                        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'secutitequestion.user_id');
                })
                ->select('secutitequestion.securite_question1'
                        ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question1'
                        ,'secutitequestion.securite_question2'
                        ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question2'
                        ,'secutitequestion.securite_question3'
                        ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question3')
                ->get();
```

Comment: I don't get the error but just i get only " 'secutitequestion.securite_question1'
                        ,'secutitequestion.answer_securite_question1'" why?

Comment: Maybe these columns doesn't exist in your table. Can you replace ->pluck(.....) with ->get(); just remove all columns and ->pluck and call ->get()

Comment: no i have them yes i try get and i get them but with user data